# Retrieve data from different column from different table and display onto textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

How to retrieve data from database to be displayed onto textbox. Like in my page, I have 2 textboxes. I need to retrieve column B from TempTab , column C from CarTab and display onto textbox 1 and 2 respectively. I hope you can help me. Examples are welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There are milions of tutorials teaching how to retrieve data from the database on the internet, just google it. Second, what have you tried, what problems are you having, what are the table formats and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with this code

```
 var connetionString = "..";
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString))
    {       

     using(var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT COLUMN1, COLUMN2 FROM YOURTABLE", connection))
     { 
       connection.Open();
       var  dr = cmmand.ExecuteReader();
       if (dr.HasRows == false)
       {
         throw new Exception();
       }
       if (dr.Read())
       {

           textBox1.Text = dr[0].ToString();
           textBox2.Text = dr[1].ToString();
       }

     } 

}
```

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate that!

Comment: I'am happy to help you Color Shadow

Comment: +1 for your solution. Will try to work with your coding first :) Have a nice day

Comment: Thank you Color Shadow you' are nice

Answer (score 0):

You may check the example [here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/95937/how-to-retrieve-data-and-display-in-textbox-in-c)

Hope it helps you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some beginner ADO help. Get started here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz.aspx